# What is wrong with XPath expression

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Sorry I`m new for this stuff.
I have this (was unable to format my code properly so I splitted it in two blocks bellow):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="EricssonSpecificAttributes.14.04.xsd"
   xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd"
   xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
   <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName="Ericsson"/>
   <un:UtranCell id="U1">
      <un:attributes>
         <un:localCellId>1</un:localCellId>
         <un:uarfcnUl>9886</un:uarfcnUl>
         <un:uarfcnDl>10836</un:uarfcnDl>
         <un:primaryScramblingCode>335</un:primaryScramblingCode>
         <un:primaryCpichPower>300</un:primaryCpichPower>
         <un:maximumTransmissionPower>400</un:maximumTransmissionPower>
         <un:primarySchPower>-18</un:primarySchPower>
         <un:cId>1</un:cId>
         <un:userLabel>U_TST33_1</un:userLabel>
         <un:secondarySchPower>-35</un:secondarySchPower>
         <un:bchPower>-31</un:bchPower>
         <un:lac>65006</un:lac>
         <un:rac>6</un:rac>
         <un:sac>1</un:sac>
         <un:uraList>65006</un:uraList>
      </un:attributes>
   </un:UtranCell>
   <fileFooter dateTime="2016-04-13T15:11:31Z"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

I`m trying to do

```
xpath_expr = "//{configData.xsd}bulkCmConfigDataFile/{utranNrm.xsd}UtranCell"
ucells = tree.xpath(xpath_expr)
```

But get en error:

```
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2186, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:60010)
File "xpath.pxi", line 359, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:152734)
File "xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:151097)
File "xpath.pxi", line 213, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:150950)
```

lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

What's wrong with what I am doing?
By the way, executing this

```
tree = etree.parse(infile)
root = tree.getroot()
print 'Root tag: ', root.tag
for child_of_root in root:
        print 'Child tags: ', child_of_root.tag, child_of_root.attrib
```

Gives this output:

```
 - Root tag:  {configData.xsd}bulkCmConfigDataFile
 - Child tags:  {utranNrm.xsd}UtranCell {'id': 'U1'}
```

Comment: Is this `lxml.etree`? Standard-library ElementTree? Something else?

Comment: Yes, lml.etree: tree = etree.parse(infile)
root = tree.getroot()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml context for variable "root" is already positioned at <bulkCmConfigDataFile> node so the xpath should be written relative to this node.

eg.

```
ucells = root.findall("un:UtranCell", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'} )
```

or

```
ucells = root.findall("{utranNrm.xsd}UtranCell")
```

*Personally, I prefer the first option, since the namespaces can be defined once and ultimately makes the xpaths far more readable.*

This will return a list of elements which you can then iterate with

```
 for cell in ucells:
     print cell.get('id')
```

Alternatively, if you're know there is only 1 UtranCell to be had, use root.find() to return a single element.

Comment: Perfect! But the source file is not known for me. It can consist of one ore more cells. Moreover, each cell can have one or more group of childs, each group can have one or more subchild, etc.. So it seems more useful to use tree.xpath to create original structure in the memory, not only list of ucells. It seems I can not look through the all elements in original structure (node/child/subchild/child_of_subchild/etc.) ussing root.findall, does not it?

Comment: As it stands, you'l just get the UtranCell nodes that sit directly under bulkCmConfigDataFile; the child nodes will not be considered.   If you want to include all of the child nodes in as single list in ucells then replace the xpath with ".//un:UtranCell"; they'll be listed in document order.   Or, if you need to keep a track of the parent whille traversing the xml tree,  use  cell.findall("un:UtranCell"  ... ) and loop through all the children recursively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I want to keep track of the parent. But what about xpath in my case? I suppose something simple we are missed in the expression. Or this way is not possible in that case?

Comment: Cant see your example but i'd use a recursvie function..  a bit like this..  (note: this is untested and badly formatted in a comment so only here to give you a gist)   def TraverseChildren(parent):
   ucells = parent.findall("{utranNrm.xsd}UtranCell")
   for cell in ucells:  print cell.get('id') TraverseChildren(cell) return

Comment: I have formatted it thank you very much. Is it right to call the function in the code: TraverseChildren(tree.getroot())?

Comment: sure.   If you need to learn more, get examples or test out ideas, checkout pythonfiddle.com

Comment: If it is possible one more question. With your fruitfull support I can read childs in section /bulkCmConfigDataFile/un:UtranCell/un:attributes. Could you please recommend the way to get text of some of attributes. Just for now I use this path: child_l1 = params.findall("un:uarfcnDl", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'}) and get U1
[<Element {utranNrm.xsd}uarfcnDl at 0x2698990>]. How could I retrieve text "10836" from the example file: <un:uarfcnDl>10836</un:uarfcnDl>? I tried print child_l1.find("un:uarfcnDl").text and get error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'.

Comment: text between two tags (as opposed to a attriute value) is a "text node".  fromthe element object "cell", you can use cell.text to get the value.  There lots of good reference here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Got it! print '+++++++ Many thanks to Phil B. It works!' ucells = root.findall("un:UtranCell", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'}) for cell in ucells: attribs = cell.findall("un:attributes", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'}) for params in attribs: child_p1 = params.findall("un:uarfcnDl", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'}) child_p2 = params.findall("un:primaryScramblingCode", namespaces={'un':'utranNrm.xsd'}) print cell.get('id'), child_p1[0].text, child_p2[0].text print '+++++++ Many thanks to Phil B. It works!'